# Retrieving auto-generated keys for an INSERT statement

Tags: postgresql, db2, db2-luw

What is the best way to retrieve an  auto-generated keys after an INSERT statement ?

After searching online for DB2 I found this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0057053.html

Is there a way to do it without using java ?

Preferably I would work using python so `ibm_db`.

Can such a thing be done on a postgres database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this in Db2 for LUW.

Firstly, there is a function [`IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004231.html) that returns one most recently assigned identity value; it can be used when inserting single records:

```
insert into parent_tab (some_column) values ('foobar');
insert into child_tab (parent_id, some_other_col) 
  values (identity_val_local(), 42);
```

assuming `parent_tab` in the example has an identity column `id`.

Another option is to use a [*data change table*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0011133.html):

```
with parent_res (parent_id) as (
  select id from final table (
    insert into parent_tab (some_column) values ('foobar')
  )
)
insert into child_tab (parent_id, some_other_col) 
select parent_id, 42 from parent_res;
```

The data change table will contain as many rows as are affected by the corresponding DML statement.

In Postgres a similar result can be achieved by using the `RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement:

```
with parent_res (parent_id) as (
  insert into parent_tab (some_col) values ('foo') returning id
)
insert into child_tab (parent_id, some_other_col) 
select parent_id, 42 from parent_res
```

Since the Postgres `IDENTITY` (formerly known as `SERIAL`) columns are backed by SQL sequences, you can also use the [`LASTVAL()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-sequence.html) function to retrieve the most recently assigned identity (sequence) value in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Returning is available in popular db . Like

> INSERT INTO .. RETURNING *

Put what you want to return from db.

Store the result like

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.ecexuteQuery();
rs.next();
long pk = rs.getLong(1);
```

here i return `rs.getLong(1);`, Return what you want. You can find more information [here](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/insert-returning/).